# Notepad++ user-defined color scheme not working for javascript

Tags: notepad++, javascript, color-theme

None of the words in the user defined style written in the user defined box have the differentiated style in them. When I try to add user keywords in the keywords style the highlight works properly. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Just checking... did you select Javascript from the Languages list (one of the top level menus)? If you have not yet saved the file so it has no extension it can't guess which language are using

Comment: Yes, I have selected Javascript and all the other custom alterations I did to the style work just fine, only the user-defined style that is not being displayed